Derivative of a convolution integral
I'm reading this material Topics in inverse problems and I'm having difficulty in understanding how the derivative of a convolution integral was obtained.
In equation 4.5 (page 91), the function $y(t)$ is defined as
$y(t) = \int_0^T g(t-s)x(s)ds$, with $t \in [0,T]$ and functions $x$ and $g : [0,T]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
Then, in equation 4.7, the derivative of $y(t)$ with respect to $t$ is
$y'(t) = g(t)x(t) +\int_0^T g'(t-s)x(s)ds$, $t \in [0,T]$.
I don't get why the term $g(t)x(t)$ appears in this derivative.

It doesn't seem to make sense it should just be
$$y'(t)=\int_0^T\partial_t,g(t-s)x(s),\mathrm ds.$$
It can be checked manually using some example function that it isn't the same.

The function $g$ is the same Kernel defined one pages above your equation ?

@Conreu, thanks. I actually did that setting x(t)=g(t)=t. It seems wrong indeed.

@Hamdiken, I don't think so. g(t) is unspecified.
